# Replace invalid character in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace an invalid character in a text string. The character is '�', when it should be 'ä'.

In firefox and chrome it is ok when parsing to xml but in internet explorer it is giving problems.

What would be the regular expression if the character is in the word "Biärt"?

Using this from other thread here is not working

```
myString = myString.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tey this code

```
    myString= myString.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better make sure that your string has correct character encoding.

For example you can setup your script encoding by

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
var responseTextt = request.responseText.replace(/[^\x00-\xFF]/g, "ä");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
 myString = myString.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ,.?!]/ig, '');
 // accept letters, numbers, space, and a few punctuation characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier, the encoding of the .DAE file was wrong.

FIXED